# Access DB - Get last index number

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to insert a new employee into a table with a custom ID field when a form saves (Before Insert).  To create the custom ID I am using the first 4 letters of the last name and the first 2 numbers of the first name, followed by a 2 digit number that is generated by the number of matching employee names:

i.e.

```
John Smith = SMITJO01 (first entry)
John Smith = SMITJO02 (second John Smith)
```

However, I do not know how to add the unique index (01, 02) into the function depending on how many other matching names are in the list:

```
Function GetNextEmployeeId(ByVal lastName As String, ByVal firstName As String) As String

    Dim strNameComp As String
    Dim nSEQ As Long

    strNameComp = Left(lastName, 4) & Left(firstName, 2)

End Function
```

Edit:
Since the EMPLOYEE_ID is the primary key, it keeps giving meNull errors when I try to save a new entry, both on the BeforeUpdate and BeforeInsert form events.

Updating with my final solution, I had to modify because it was being finicky about formatting to numbers.  Thanks to both you guys for the help!

```
Function GetNextEmployeeId(ByVal lastName As String, ByVal firstName As String) As String

    Dim strNameComp As String
    'Dim varMax As Var
    Dim nSEQ As Long

    strNameComp = UCase(Left(lastName, 4)) & UCase(Left(firstName, 2))

    varMax = DMax("EMPLOYEE_ID", "EMPLOYEES", "EMPLOYEE_ID LIKE '" & strNameComp & "*'")

    If IsNull(varMax) Then
        ' no one there yet
        nSEQ = 1
    Else
        ' split off the number part, convert to number, add 1
        nSEQ = Val(Right$(varMax, 2)) + 1
    End If

    GetNextEmployeeId = UCase(strNameComp) & Format(nSEQ, "00")

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Andre's suggestion of using `DMax`, try something like this:

```
Function GetNextEmployeeId(ByVal lastName As String, ByVal firstName As String) As String
    Dim strPre As String
    Dim varMax As String

    strPre = Left(lastName, 4) & Left(firstName, 2)
    varMax = DMax("EmployeeId", "tblEmployee", "EmployeeId LIKE '" & strPre & "*'")

    GetNextEmployeeId = strPre & Right("0" & Right(Nz(varMax, "0"), 2) + 1, 2)
End Function
```

Comment: I have edited the original question, as I am having difficulty using the suggested function changes when I try to save the form.

Comment: I have tried both suggestions, and calling the function in the form's BeforeInsert and BeforeUpdate events.  I get "Invalid use of Null" when I try typing in new first and last name on BeforeInsert, and "Index or primary key cannot contain a null value" on BeforeUpdate when I try to save.

Answer (score 0):

Get the **maximum** Employee ID that matches the Name:

```
varMax = DMax("EmployeeId", "tblEmployee", "EmployeeId LIKE '" & strNameComp & "*'")
```

and then you need a distinction:

```
If IsNull(varMax) Then
    ' no one there yet
    nSEQ = 1
Else
    ' split off the number part, convert to number, add 1
    nSEQ = Val(Right$(varMax, 2)) + 1
End If
```

Comment: And then prefix with leading zero if necessary, using `Right("0" & nSEQ,2)`

Comment: That is probably what I am needing for this to work, but when I use 

    Me.EMPLOYEE_ID = EmployeeNumber.GetNextEmployeeId(Me.LAST_NAME, Me.FIRST_NAME)

on the Form_BeforeInsert event, When I click save it give me a warning that the Index or Primary Key cannot be Null.  Which event would I call this on so it uses the Function GetNextEmployeeId before this is saved?